# Need to convert hex value to ascii dec with # sign in front

Tags: hex, ascii, delphi-xe7

```
check1, check2: AnsiString;
begin
    //How come this works?
    check1 := #130;//  Checksum

    // But not this
    check2 := '#' + IntToStr($82);
end;
```

If I know the checksum it works and assigns the check variable with #130.
But when I calculate the checksum to 130 I have to concatenate # and 130, it does not work.

Comment: I want to create the decimal value #130 which is hex 82, but the string '#130' is not the same as #130. I dont want the character. This is what I want check2 := # + IntToStr($82);

Comment: I want to create the decimal value #130 which is hex 82, but the string '#130' is not the same as #130. I dont want the character. This is what I want check2 := # + IntToStr($82); But that gives error "E2026 constant expression expected" @ Dalija Prasnikar

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what you are trying to do but two assignments you are using are doing very different things.

`check1 := #130;` will put ANSI character with byte value `130` into string, `#` outside string literals `''` tells the compiler that you are defining character with specific byte value - depending on encoding resulting string value will be `'é'`

`check2 := '#' + IntToStr($82);` will just concatenate `'#'` character with string value of `$82` integer constant - `'130'` so resulting string value will be `'#130'`

If you are trying to put character with some calculated value into string then you should be using `chr` function

```
check2 := chr($82);
```

There is also [{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)) compiler directive that defines how will character literals be interpreted by compiler in Delphi 2009 and newer versions

> When `HIGHCHARUNICODE` is `OFF`:
>
> All decimal #xxx n-digit literals are parsed as AnsiChar. All
>   hexadecimal #$xx 2-digit literals are parsed as AnsiChar. All
>   hexadecimal #$xxxx 4-digit literals are parsed as WideChar.
>
> When `HIGHCHARUNICODE` is `ON`: All literals are parsed as WideChar.

```
 var
   A: AnsiChar;
   W: WideChar;

 begin

 {$HIGHCHARUNICODE OFF}
   A := #$80; // Ord(A) = $80
   W := #$80; // Ord(W) depends on default ANSI codepage; for example
              //   = $0402 for Win1251 codepage ('Ђ')
              //   = $20AC for Win1252 codepage ('€');

 {$HIGHCHARUNICODE ON}
   A := #$80; // Ord(A) = $3F ('?')
   W := #$80; // Ord(W) = $80

   A := #200; // Ord(A) depends on default ANSI codepage; for example
              //   = $45 for Win1251 codepage ('E')
              //   = $C8 for Win1252 codepage ('È');
   W := #200; // Ord(W) = 200 ($C8) 

 end;
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `#nnn` and `#$xx` literals in the 128-255 range are subject to the [`{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)) directive in D2009+.